# How can I clear gaps in the Binding of Isaac?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I have coins. I have bombs. I lack keys and health. Obviously means I found a key and a heart pickups; they're so close, and yet so far.

[image]

Now, I know one of the devil pacts grants you flight. Is that the only way to reach those areas?

Comment: it's funny that on this screenshot you already had two possibilities to get the key (bomb to get a platform and if that fails using the tarot card)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I didn't know what the tarot did. I'm trying to keep myself reasonably unspoilt :)

Comment: #badp I know what you mean, I'm saving most unknown items, tarots and unidentified pils for mini-bosses or many enemies. Sometimes with unpleasant results though :-/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get the following pickups to cross gaps:

- Ladder - Cross 1 gap spaces
- Lord of the Pit - Gives you the permanent ability to fly
- Hanged Man Tarot Card - Gives you the ability to fly for your current
  room only, one time use
- Transcendence - Like Hanged Man, only a permanent upgrade
- The Bible - Gives you flight when used for your current room only
- A Pony - Usable item that also gives you constant flight (added on Halloween update)
- The Pinking Shears - Usable item that separates Isaac's head and body, allowing you control of the head (essentially another version of the Bible as a usable item, with added benefit of a free "Super Meat Boy" for that room while your body attacks enemies)

Credit to Chris Rasys for mentioning the Magnet, which can pull items towards you from a short distance away. While not technically the same as crossing the gap, it serves the same effect for the purpose of retrieving unobtainable items.

In this case, where there's a rock right next to the gap, using a bomb will plug the hole. This appears to be fickle though, as I've had bombs just destroy the block and not plug the hole. It appears that you have to be pretty precise in terms of the bomb placement so that the blast is exactly horizontal/vertical to the block.

Comment: While it's not the same as clearing the gaps, you can also get the magnet to pull items towards you.

Comment: @ChrisRasys Good point! Thanks for the reminder. I'll edit this in as an extra.

Comment: I'll also mention two additional items that can help: _The Bible_ turns you into an angle once used and until you leave the room, granting you flight. _Transcendence_ has the same effect as the hanged man tarot card, but its effects are constant. The demon form item mentioned by @TheQ is _Load of the Pit_, an upside-down cross.

Comment: @Aubergine Thank you for the additional info! Editing it in.

Comment: I didn't feel it necessary to edit the answer, but there are other items that give permanent flight (Spirit of the Night, Fate, and a couple Angel Room items) as well as rock-breaking (Notched Axe, The Nail, and others), just for reference.

Answer (score 3):

I think that in the case shown in the picture, a bomb would knock the rocks into the pit so you could cross.